# Why should interactive element not be used within an anchor?

Tags: html

Simply out of curiosity - I have been nailed in my previous question for trying to put button within an anchored image. I looked at documentations and other questions and although everyone is saying that it should not be done, they are not saying why.

Even the documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element states that there should be no interactive content within anchor, but does not tell me the reasoning.

Does anyone know why is it such a horrible practice to do so?

Comment: Please give a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that situation:

```html
<a href="http://google.com">
  <select>
    <option>V1</option>
    <option>V2</option>
  </select>
</a>
```

Now when you press on `select` element these actions will take effect (in order):

1. Open select dropdown.
2. Bubble `click` event to parent (`<a>` in this case).
3. `<a>` element follows it's `href` value (at this point you leave current page).
4. (after some delay by human body) You would select desired option (**but you had already left website**)

Comment: oh I was trying to find a way around it, but I guess just re designing my code would be a better solution then! Thanks!