# WCAG 4.1.2: Nested interactive controls are not announced by screen readers

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

Here is my issue in terms of the adaptive cards.

**Issue**

Nested interactive controls are not announced by screen readers (nested-interactive)

**Element path**

`#card_875c3295-31b4-eb11-8237-00224822ed9c9c945a9b-31b4-eb11-8237-00224822ed9c > .ac-adaptiveCard.ac-container > .ac-container > .ac-columnSet:nth-child(1) > .ac-selectable.ac-container[role="button"]`

**Snippet**

`div class="ac-container ac-selectable" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Open knowledge article, Order Shipping Time" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: flex-start; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 0px; flex: 1 1 50px...`

**How to fix**

Fix any of the following:

- Element has focusable descendants

**Screenshots**

[Error visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4OWT.png)

[image: DOM]

Comment: Hi can you post your complete CSS and HTML for this issue, the code you have posted is incomplete (no button, no element with the id, etc).

Comment: So there is an issue with nesting interactive controls - which one should be activated when you press Enter for example. Have a look at [this answer I gave on nested interactive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092618/2702894) and see if that helps you understand why it is a bad idea. I am guessing within the card (which you have told a screen reader to treat as a `<button>` with `role="button"`) you have other interactive elements (other buttons or hyperlinks) and that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I appended a screenshot for the DOM. I understand the issue that the button nests a focusable href. The UI is rendered by Adaptive Card (adaptivecards.js version 1.3.0). The card title here is an Action.Submit where it calls APIs. I'd appreciate it if you guys could offer some pointers. (I'm trying not to upgrade the version to the latest 2.9.0. It's a little bit expensive at the moment).

Comment: The only pointer I can give is that you contact the developers of Adaptive Card and request that they fix this. Buttons simply should not contain hyperlinks. If the framework you are using does this in a way that can't be prevented, there's a bug in the framework.

Comment: The template embeds a href in the title. This can be fixed from our side. Thanks for replying.